# Why we need both Datetime and Datetime?

Tags: c#, .net

As I was wondering we can assign Datetime a null by Datetime? (nullable) then why we want both the things in C# we can stop this `Datetime` and make Datetime? as our default data type any reason we are still following both

Comment: Why did you declare `MyStruct? mine` if you don't want a null? This would suffice: `MyStruct mine`, then this would be an error `mine = null`, this too an error: `MyStruct mine = null`

Comment: Sry my bad changed now

Comment: On your change, the comment `// Not an error` is still there. That would be a compiler error now. Test your changes here: https://ideone.com/hkHkKb

Comment: I have this error with your code: `error CS0037: Cannot convert null to 'MyStruct' because it is a value type`

Comment: Yes I'm sorry now my vs is detecting as an error this is completely irrelevant I will delete the question

Comment: @Avinash you cannot delete the question anymore, but you could edit the question to remove the first (irrelevant) question.

Comment: Btw.: being able to assign `null` is not as great as it sounds. Tony Hoare, who "invented" it famously calls it [the billion dollar mistake](https://www.infoq.com/presentations/Null-References-The-Billion-Dollar-Mistake-Tony-Hoare). And now the move is even to introduce [nullable reference types](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/nullable-reference-types-in-csharp/), which in turn would cause assigning `null` to a variable of a "normal" reference type throw (or at least warn).

Comment: Also, for a nice discussion about the inner workings of `Nullable<T>` see [this series of posts](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/20/nullable-micro-optimizations-part-one/).

Comment: @Corak: No, nullable reference types won't cause assigning a null reference to a non-nullable type variable to throw an exception. It's a compile-time only feature: the compiler will warn you if it thinks you *might* assign a null reference to a non-nullable variable, but you can still do it.

Comment: @JonSkeet - yes, you are right, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two questions, you should post it as two questions. Your question number 1 is answered on comments already.

As for number 2 question. If you want DateTime to accept null by default, that would incur changes in the framework. [DateTime is a struct](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs), which is a value type. If you want `DateTime` to accept null without declaring `DateTime?`, it need to be made as class, not as struct.

Framework authors chooses `struct` as much as possible for a data structure to prevent overhead as much possible. `struct` is a value type (like `int`, `long`, `byte`), live on the stack, so it will not allocate memory as compared to class.

So there, it's hard to negotiate to make `DateTime` a class rather than a struct. Otherwise, C# 1.0 will just be Java in Visual Studio's clothing :) One of the premise of C# is to make it faster than Java by giving developers an option to choose between value types (`struct`, `int`, `long`, `byte`) vs reference type (`class`)

Comment: Nullable values types are also value types, with the same stack/heap behaviour as non-nullable value types... not that value types always live on the stack. What's more important, IMO, is that most of the time you don't *want* null as a possible value. (Most of the time you don't want null as a possible value for reference types either, hence the changes in C# 8.)

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, nullable value types are also value types. I posted a comment (of C#'s Nullable code) on Michal's answer (deleted answer) illustrating that despite accepting null, Nullable is a struct. Things get even murkier in C# 8, as there will be a principle called "non-nullable" reference types that can be enforced (by a compiler switch?). It was simple to explain in C# 1.0, nullables are reference types, non-nullable are value types. Of course things need to improve and evolve to developers need, so old literatures can't be relied exactly as they are

Comment: It's not clear why you've got the second half of your answer. The OP wasn't asking why value types exist - they're asking why value types aren't nullable by default. Aside from not breaking everyone, it would be entirely feasible to create a language where both value types and reference types were nullable by default. Most of your answer is about "why not use classes for everything?" which is a different question.

Comment: (And non-nullable reference types aren't really enforced at execution time in C# 8. The compiler warns you if it thinks you're trying to use a value that might be null for a non-nullable type, but the IL doesn't change. There's no enforcement in the way that the rest of the type system is enforced. I tend to think of it as "optimistic typing".)

Comment: "And non-nullable reference types aren't really enforced at execution time in C# 8." Yes, in fact it mostly feels like a linter. If it can be enforced at execution, we won't be needing `catch(NullReferenceException ex)` at all. "it would be entirely feasible to create a language where both value types and reference types were nullable by default." That's a good idea, if C# can be rebooted, struct (e.g., DateTime) can be made nullable by default, but then we would have to think of the syntax of how to make nullable struct be made non-nullable, anyway syntax are trivial problem.

Comment: So yes, it made me realize now that the question is not about `struct` vs `class`, it's about making struct nullable by default